# Retrieve response metadata in interceptor in gRPC-go

Tags: go, grpc, interceptor

For short:
How can I retrieve response's initial_metadata with `grpc.WithStreamInterceptor` without wrapping `grpc.ClientStream`?

The situation is I try to use an interceptor to manage metadata in request and response from all calls. For example, append password/token to request and retrieve token from response.

First I create a struct and define a streamInterceptor

```
type ClientInterceptor struct {
    Header         string
    Value          string
    ResponseHeader string
    ResponseValue  string
}
```

```
func (client *ClientInterceptor) streamInterceptor(ctx context.Context, desc *grpc.StreamDesc, cc *grpc.ClientConn, method string, streamer grpc.Streamer, opts ...grpc.CallOption) (grpc.ClientStream, error) {
    log.Println("Add header in interceptor")
    ctx = metadata.AppendToOutgoingContext(ctx, client.Header, client.Value)
    clientStream, err := streamer(ctx, desc, cc, method, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    log.Println("Access response header")
    responseMeta, err := s.Header() // Block at here, server not trigger any function
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if val, ok := responseMeta[client.ResponseHeader]; ok {
        client.ResponseValue = val[0]
        log.Println("Response header: ", val[0])
    } else {
        return nil, status.Errorf(codes.DataLoss, "Response without header founded")
    }
    return clientStream, nil
}
```

and below is how I use it.

```
interceptor := &ClientInterceptor{Header: "x-custom", Value: "hello header", ResponseHeader: "x-custom-echo"}
conn, err := grpc.Dial("127.0.0.1:60661", grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()), grpc.WithStreamInterceptor(interceptor.streamInterceptor))
```

However, the code is always block on the line `responseMeta, err := s.Header()`, and the server shows no request.
If I remove the part of the code and use a struct to wrap `clientStream`, I can get response metadata from `RecvMsg()`

```
type wrappedStream struct {
    grpc.ClientStream
    getHeader bool
}

func (w *wrappedStream) RecvMsg(m interface{}) error {
    if !w.getHeader {
        responseMeta, err := w.Header()
        if err != nil {
            return nil
        }
        if val, ok := responseMeta["x-custom-echo"]; ok {
            log.Println("Response header: ", val[0])
        }
    }
    return w.ClientStream.RecvMsg(m)
}

func (w *wrappedStream) SendMsg(m interface{}) error {
    return w.ClientStream.SendMsg(m)
}
```

This means that every call will create it's own instance and store the token by their own, which is not what I want.
I know I can use a pointer to share the values, but it seems a bit "dirty".
According to the [gRPC official document](https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/core-concepts/#unary-rpc), initial_metadata can be send first without body(protobuf).
How can I forced metadata to be send in interceptor, since server will response metadata first when request header comes (request body is unnecessary).

To reproduce the situation, I write it in [gist](https://gist.github.com/codingbaobao/f89291866024a97c1b476a682f82c029)
if you need.